# How to pass data from frontend javascript to backend node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, frontend, backend

I am attempting to parse data from an excel file into json on the frontend then take the json data and send it to some backend node.js for processing and manipulation. Ideally, the backend will return a status for display back on the frontend if successful. Complete noob to frontend and backend javascript.  Do I need to be using jquery or ajax? here is my code for the frontend.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://catamphetamine.github.io/read-excel-file/read-excel-file.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <H3>Read Excel File Client Side</H3>
    <input type="file" id="input" />
    <pre id="result1"></pre>
    <pre id="result2"></pre>
</body>
<script>
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    input.addEventListener('change', function () {
        readXlsxFile(input.files[0], {
            dateFormat: 'MM/DD/YY'
        }).then(function (data) {
            // `data` is an array of rows
            // each row being an array of cells.
            document.getElementById('result1').innerText = data;

            document.getElementById('result2').innerText = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)
        }, (error) => {
            console.error(error)
            alert("Error while parsing Excel file. See console output for the error stack trace.")
        })
    })
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So technically, you can do such operation on Frontend but it's waste of client resource.
When you're writing frontend app, you must think how your application will be used. You need to assume, clients will use it on low-end devices such as old smartphones. Because of that, we're trying to move heavy computation to backend part.

What I would tell you is to just receive Excel file trough your website, send it to Node.js backend and process it there, so that frontend can focus on UserExperience (UX) and backend can focus on business logic.

As for if you need jquery or ajax -> no, you don't need neither of them.
jQuery is a lib that made it easy back in a day to execute same code on different browsers as browsers had different APIs ( some had more, some had less, not everything was as unified as it's now ). In 2018, in my opinion there is totally no reason to use jQuery in modern browsers as browsers have excellent API which can do same things without dependencies). As for AJAX, you can use it but since you're beginner I would advise not to.

Try to build super simple HTML page with form element and file input, and send it to you Node.js backend server. Then try to write Node.js server ( I would advice not to use any ready solutions, because you won't learn too much ) and convert this file into meaningul data structure. Then you can process it and send response to your frontend page.